# Cannot get blurry background when Bootstrap modal is opened

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, blur

I am using [Bootstrap 5.1.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/) and I would like to *blur the background when a modal opens* with the CSS [backdrop-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) property.

The simplest approach I tried is:

```css
.modal-backdrop {
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

[Live demo](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/YzjxOQm)

I am using the latest Firefox browser, but the results are the same in Chrome (Windows 11).

I tried many variants suggested everywhere, but none of them work. The background simply never gets blurred.

Can anybody get the background to blur with `backdrop-filter`? What am I missing here?

Comment: Check once the Updated code is. I'm Update according to your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply your style to the `#exampleModal`, as follows:

```css
#exampleModal {
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: You're definitely onto something here. When I use `.modal { backdrop-filter: blur(5px); }` it works for all my modals. Weird. Why doesn't this work when I apply the filter to the actual backdrop of the modal?

Comment: there is no element with `modal-backdrop` class in your html in demo you provided

Comment: modal-backdrop class is generated from bootstrap 5

Comment: Yes, there is a `modal-backdrop` once the modal is opened, so its absence is not the reason.

Comment: I think the main reason why applying the `backdrop-filter` to the actual backdrop of the modal doesn't work is because the backdrop has a rather low opacity value. This opacity affects the degree to which the filtering is visible, which makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change in CSS and HTML structure according below code.

---

### Using backdrop-filter

```css
.modal-open .modal-backdrop {
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>This text should get blurred when the modal is opened.</h1>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Using filter

```css
.modal-open .main-wrapper {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="main-wrapper">
<h1>This text should get blurred when the modal is opened.</h1>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this works as well. I think the opacity of the modal backdrop affects the degree to which the backdrop-filter effect is visible, which makes sense.